# How to change the position of the modeline?

Tags: mode-line

My visual impression of a highlighted modeline placed below the horizontal scrollbar is to intuitively consider the modeline to belong to the window below and not to the window above:

[image: highlighted modeline]

After two weeks of Emacs usage it is still irritating me, especially if I had two or more displayed horizontal windows.

Is there a way to display the modeline at the top of the window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*To my current knowledge you can't display the modeline at the top of the window.*

But you can use a [header-line](http://www.gnu.org/s/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Header-Lines.html) assigning to its format the format of the [mode-line](http://www.gnu.org/s/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Mode-Line-Data.html) and then switch-off the visualization of the mode-line by adding to your ~/.emacs (or other initialization file) following two lines:

```
(setq-default header-line-format mode-line-format)
(setq-default mode-line-format nil)
```

[image: header-line]